# Logic: cardinality of the set of formulas

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, model-theory

How can you proof that $||L||=|L|$ if $L$ is infinite (where $||L||$ stands for the cardinality of the set of all $L$-formulas and $|L|$ the number of all constants, function and relation symbols)?

The case where $L$ is finite is clear for me, because in that case you can just count all the formulas by an induction argument, so $||L||=|\mathbb{N}|$.

Comment: **Hint**: Formulae are finite strings. (Not posted as an answer because it's probably too terse for that.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $X$ is an infinite set and $X^*$ is the set of finite lists of elements of $X$, then $\mbox{card}(X) = \mbox{card}(X^*)$. Taking $X$ to be the set of all constant, function, relation and logical symbols, the set of all formulas is a subset of $X^*$ and hence $\|L\| \le \mbox{card}(X) = |L|$ (where the equality holds because $L$ is infinite and there are only finitely many logical symbols). The converse inequality $|L| \le \|L\|$  holds (without the assumption that $L$ is infinite) because given a constant, function or relation symbol you can construct a formula containing that symbol (and no other constant, function or relation symbol, e.g. $\mathbf{c} = \mathbf{c}$ or $\forall x\cdot\mathbf{f}(x) = \mathbf{f}(x)$ or $\forall x \cdot \mathbf{R}(x)$).

Comment: Could you please give some more explicit explaination for your last sentence? I am not quite understand that why given a constand, function or relation symbol we can construct a formula. Is that the fact that every variable is itself an expression, and for any symbol itself is an expression as well?

Comment: I've updated the answer to try to clarify that point. Does that help?

Comment: If the set of all formulas is a subset of $X^*$ then I guess that means that variables are considered logical symbols? No, that can't right, because you say there are only finitely many logical symbols.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It makes sence to me. But here, are we assuming that the set and functions or predicate symbol must be non-empty? Otherwise we connot have any expression.