# In general, how to determine the cardinality of the set of expression over a language?

Tags: combinatorics, logic, cardinals, first-order-logic, formal-languages

For a given language **L**, with its set of variables $V$, function symbols $F$, relation symbols $R$. Once we are given the cardinality of $V$, $F$, $R$. Is there any way to define the cardinality of the set of expressions over this language?

I think maybe there can be a systematic way to find the cardinality (which may be very messy, but if it is such a way to deal with that, I really wish to learn about it also). And also I expect to learn (if there are) some useful tricks to determine it simply use the relation of the size of the set of expressions and the size of finite strings (which can be find much easily in this related question below).

Related question:

[Logic: cardinality of the set of formulas](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/474975/logic-cardinality-of-the-set-of-formulas)

[The cardinality of a language over a set of variables $V$ with $\#V= κ$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2264169/the-cardinality-of-a-language-over-a-set-of-variables-v-with-v-%CE%BA)

Both of above seems talked about the set of **finite strings**

So could someone give some way to determine the size of the set of expression? Any help will be appreciate.

Comment: See [Cardinal arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number#Cardinal_addition).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I do have learnt the laws of cardinal arithmetic. Now I am considering what to put into the set of **expression**, not simply **strings**. For the set of strings we can simplely count the length, but now considering the **expressions**, I even do not know what to put into the set and how to do the counting. May I please ask for some more explicit hint?

Comment: The "basic" facts are two: *(i)* the set of *variables* is countable. Thus, irrespective of any function, constant and predicate symbols, the set of symbols is countable. *(ii)* an *expressions* is a *finite* string of symbols: thus, the set of expression is countable. We may have sets of symbols of cardinality different from $\aleph_0$; in this cases, apply the rules of cardinal arithmetic.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA But now I am considering any general case, even if we usually have countablely many variables, now I need to consider any cardinality of $V,F,R$ including countable and uncountable case. So may I please ask for some argument about the uncountable case as well?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA And also, I am worrying about the finite case.

Comment: The set of variables is countable; thus, with only a finite number of functions, predicates and constants (consider a simple example: set-theory: two binary predicates and one constant; no function) the set of finite strings is countable.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA It is not what I mean... I am asking for the set $V$ to be uncountable. We cannot assume it is countable here.

Comment: If the set of const+funct+pred has card $κ$ then the set of expressions has card $\aleph_0 + κ$.

Comment: See answer to [the-cardinality-of-a-language-over-a-set-of-variables-v](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2264169/the-cardinality-of-a-language-over-a-set-of-variables-v-with-v-%ce%ba).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA This is infact another question I asked... Now I am considering **expressions**. But the answers only gives the argument about **strings**. So what I do need is some conclusion about **expressions**, what can we do once we know about the strings?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I do know how to determine the cardinality of strings for any cardinality of variables, I only need to consider what to do for determine for the subset of **strings** which is **expressions**. How does it related to tht of **strings**, for any cardinality with $3$ cases: 1.finite 2. countablely infinite 3. uncountablely infinite. I know that maybe to some experts it makes no obvious different. But now I am so confused.

Comment: If expressions means well-formed formulas, obviously if the set of string has cardinality $\aleph_0$, also the set of wff has. (i) every wff is an expression and (ii) for every var $x_i$ we can build the wff $x_i=x_i$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes it does mean the wff's! But I cannot quite understand why the cardinality of the wff same as that of strings? It seems not obvious to me...Or they are the same only if the set of string is countable? From your (ii) I can only conclude that its cardinality is not smaller then that of expressions

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA For (ii), are we assuming the relation symbol $"="\in R$?